# C++ - How can I input strings from user into a vector string and then perform some operation on based of that?

Tags: c++, string, vector, conditional-statements

How do I make this work?

```
char stringw[];                   //to hold the data user enters and then copy it to the string vector .. I didnt know any direct method
cin>>stringw;                     
directions.push_back(stringw);    //directions is a <string> vector
```

How do I make such a check?
`if(directions[i][j])=="N")    //I am getting an error`
`"error: expected primary-expression before '==' token"`

Edit 1: **Error Solved** `if(directions[i][j])=="N")` should be `if(directions[i][j]=="N")` I closed the parantheses unexpectedly

Now How do we add string data to string vector?

Edit 2 : ***Solved!***

Actually using `char stringw` is of data type char * and I am pushing `char *` into a string ... it doesn't that way.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<string> data;
    string temp;
    std::cin >> temp;
    data.push_back(temp);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a wrong ')' after directions[i][j].
The correct way is:

```
if(directions[i][j]=='N')
```

Comment: To add string data to string vector you  need write push_back(s), where s is string.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `stringw` is of the type `char *` and so it is not compatible with the vector you have defined.

There are two workarounds to your issue

1. Change the vector to

   `vector <char *> directions;`
2. Change `stringw` to

   `string stringw;`

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s;
    vector<string> ss;
    cin >> s;
    ss.push_back(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should put some explanation of your code here.

Answer (score 0):

Use `vector`:

```
// Declare vectors
vector<string> directions;
vector<string> stringw;
string str;
```

And a loop to write into the vector:

```
// Create string inside vector: 'q' to exit loop
while (cin >> str && str != "q")
   stringw.emplace_back(str);
```

Copy contents to other vector:

```
// Copy contents to 'directions'
copy(begin(stringw), end(stringw), back_inserter(directions));
```